# GIMP does not launch

Tags: gimp

I downloaded GIMP 2.8 yestereday. Immediately it installed, I tried to open it but windows gave me an error message that the program stopped. I restarted my computer but nothing changed. Pls help me. I use windows7. The error message is:a problem made the program  to stop. Windows will notify you if a solution is available

Comment: I'm not sure if this even on-topic for SO (looks more suitable for superuser.com), but you should at least add the error message to your post.

Comment: Many possible reasons for this, like DLL conflicts. Where did you download it from? download.gimp.org? partha.com(\*)? or some less reputable source? (\*) Builds from partha.com come with the more useful/popular plugins pre-installed, so they are a good alternative to the official ones.

Comment: Font cache creation on first run is the most likely cause for this particular problem, btw - the workaround is to wait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the "portable" version of Gimp, instead. No installation, no dlls, no register mess, no broken links, garbage folders, nothing. You even can run it right from a pendrive, no matter if you are at your home or no: Gimp will be with you. Free, riskless, easy and 100% legal: http://portableapps.com/apps